# htaccess Mod Rewrite rule for multiple URLs and PHP $_GET's

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these mod rewrite rules in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Displays directory if there is no / on the end of the URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/status [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer [NC]

# Removes index.php from URL 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

# Rewrites /services to be /index.php?id=services
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rewrites /blog/this-is-a-blog-post to be /index.php?id=blog&slug=this-is-a-blog-post
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,QSA]

# Rewrites /blog/year2013/month12 to be /index.php?id=blog&year=2013&month=01
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/year([0-9]+)/month([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]

# Rewrites /status/123 to be /index.php?id=status&seq=123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&seq=$2 [L,QSA]

# Rewrites /status/cat1 to be /index.php?id=status&cat=1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/cat([0-9]+)?$ /index.php?id=$1&cat=$2 [L,QSA]
```

the `/blog` works fine, but `/status` doesn't. its showing the directory index of even tho there is no directory

i basically want:

1. `home.php?id=services to look like domain.com/services` (this for
   multiple links/URLs) - **Works fine**
2. `home.php?id=blog&year=2013&month=12` to look like
   `domain.com/blog/year2013/month12` **Works fine**
3. `home.php?id=blog&slug=this-is-a-blog-post` to look like
   `domain.com/blog/this-is-a-blog-post` **Works fine**
4. `home.php?id=status&cat=123` to be `domain.com/status/cat123` **Not working**
5. `home.php?id=blog&seq=456` to be `domain.com/status/456` **Not working**

as you can see above only numbers 4 and 5 don't work, they are just showing either index of or 404 page not found however there is no directory stored on the web server with a name of *status*

how can I fix my code above to get this working as the list above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change regex in `/status/123` rule to make it capture only numbers and hyphens and bring `/blog/this-is-a-blog-post` rule below it.

Use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Displays directory if there is no / on the end of the URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|status|customer) [NC]
# Removes index.php from URL 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

# Rewrites /services to be /index.php?id=services
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rewrites /blog/year2013/month12 to be /index.php?id=blog&year=2013&month=01
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/year([0-9]+)/month([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]

# Rewrites /status/123 to be /index.php?id=status&seq=123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([\d-]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&seq=$2 [L,QSA]

# Rewrites /blog/this-is-a-blog-post to be /index.php?id=blog&slug=this-is-a-blog-post
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,QSA]

# Rewrites /status/cat1 to be /index.php?id=status&cat=1
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/cat([0-9]+)?$ /index.php?id=$1&cat=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: When I go to domain.com/status/cat1 I just shows /status page but if I do /status?cat=1 that works fine. When it shows index.php?id=status it includes status.php so the actual page it is showing is status.php?cat=1

Comment: Check my update. Not sure if my above comment made sense

Comment: Alright provably I misunderstood some of your retirement. Request you to please provide the URLs that don't work in your question and I will test it out once I get back to my computer and update my answer.